# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in eloquent Polymorphic

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-relationship

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'productName',
        'quantity',
        'weight',
        'boxes',
        'MRP',
        'costprice',
        'productDescription',
        'seller_id',
        'category_id'
    ];

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Image::class,'imageable');
    }
}
```

```php
class Image extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'url',
        'size',
        'filename',
        'imageable_id',
        'imageable_type',
    ];

    public function imageable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

```php
class ProductController extends Controller 
{
    function index()
    {
        $product = Product::with('image')->get(); 

        return view('layouts.ecommerce.productAvailable', compact('product'));
    }
}
```

```xml
<!---------productAvailable.blade.php--------------
@foreach($product as $key => $val) 
    <td>{{ $val['image']['id'] }}</td>
@endforeach
```

> i am unable to traverse through relation but when i am using $val['image'] it is returning a collection

```xml
@foreach($product as $key => $val) 
    <td>{{ $val['image'] }}</td>
@endforeach
```

```
{"id":3,"imageable_id":14,"imageable_type":"App\\Models\\Product","url":"images\/j1zRX7Cs1DaWFWc1hIi9c17A7Pzj9G7tUMdj576q.jpg","size":"51313","filename":"1643628568.blacky.jpg","created_at":"2022-01-31T11:29:29.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-01-31T11:29:29.000000Z"}
{"id":4,"imageable_id":24,"imageable_type":"App\\Models\\Product","url":"images\/Dz05JmPPuGFSFOO2U1gcb2LJHAz7H63BLGZtPWdQ.jpg","size":"281910","filename":"1643629631.starlet.jpg","created_at":"2022-01-31T11:47:11.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-01-31T11:47:11.000000Z"}
{"id":5,"imageable_id":26,"imageable_type":"App\\Models\\Product","url":"images\/vDdYJKfhy3vzHnfJmxBWA7H8qY1M6Ph9ccfBmc0X.jpg","size":"80911","filename":"1643629652.chuhiya3.jpg","created_at":"2022-01-31T11:47:32.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-01-31T11:47:32.000000Z"}
```

Comment: try $val->image  instead  $val['image']['id']

Comment: i have tried it already it is returning collection of image but when i am trying to access specific column it is returning error

Comment: then you use foreach loop like foreach($product as $key => $val) foreach($val->image as $val) {{$val->image}} endforeach endforeach

Comment: I also did that but it is still showing error